# cloning a xml node without cloning values inside

Tags: java, xml, dom

Im trying to write a java program using xml dom.  i just want to clone a particular  node and put different information in it every time.  i cant figure out how to clone a node with out copying the values(textnode values) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider subclassing the Node and override the behavior for cloning.